# PS4 controller keeps disconnecting

Tags: ps4, controllers

I bought a new PS4 controller on Amazon but while I'm using it randomly disconnects. I don't get a message saying that it's been disconnected but the light starts blinking and it becomes unresponsive and reconnects after a few seconds.

I've tried resetting the controller and reconnecting it which fixed the problem for about a day but started disconnecting again. This only happens to my new controller, my other one never disconnects. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you verified that your old controller works fine, its most likely your new ps4 controller. Another possible test you can do it try it on another PS4 system at a friends home.

Since you purchased from Amazon, you might have a defective ps4 controller. You can just do a no hassle return with amazon and get another one. Go here to amazon returns here: https://www.amazon.com/gp/orc/returns/homepage.html